# sub-Image comparison in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, image-comparison

I am working on a WPF application where I have some screenshots. Now in all these screenshots I have to check whether any of the screenshot contains a certain smaller size image(sub-image).

I have looked into different solutions but every solution compares 2 images whether they are exact or not. But I need something which will tell me whether a image contains another image or not.

Comment: Maybe some local [Cross-Correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) would do the trick?

Comment: Normally for even comparing two pictures from different sources, it would require you to use an algorithm with difference-thresholds. But assuming the sub-images you're looking for and your target image source are same in resolution and their quality is intact, you could just iterate through the pixels on your screenshots: do a Bitmap comparision from each pixel for the given target resolution and check if they match the target image. That said this kind of computation would require a lot of processing time, unless you could use some sort of GPU acceleration  API for it.